# Bash-shell two file match successfully , but output wrong

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
cat file1.txt
cheng 600
huang 500
pan 400
yin 300

cat file2.txt
600 a
300 c
```

when  I execute the command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$1]}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

The output is below:

```
 cheng 600
 yin 300
```

But i expected should be like this:

```
 cheng 600 a
 yin 300 c
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt

cheng 600 a
yin 300 c
```

Comment: I see, I should eidt the print dialogue with {print $1,$2,a[$2]},not a[$1]. like below:                                                                                                                    
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt